# Strange issues with a new device creation in AVD for motorola razr (540x960)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-virtual-device

I have been testing my xml layouts for multiple screen sizes using Android emulator. 
I created a new device in the AVD for Motorola Razr (Resolution: 540x960), size (in inch) = 4.3, hdpi.

Strangely enough, the **metrics.height** comes out to be 888 instead of 960, whereas **metrics.width** is correct (=540).

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Log.i("widthPx: ", ""+metrics.widthPixels);  // comes out 540
Log.i("heightPx", ""+metrics.heightPixels); // comes out 888 ?? How come ??
```

Now, my problem is how do I rely on this virtual device while testing my layouts. I also created a new AVD with the resolution 540x1032 whose width & height comes out to be exactly 540x960 programmatically (intentionally added 88px to 960px (==1032) to get the desired height). Should i rely on this device instead? I'm confused.

Also i double checked that every details in my AVD are correctly entered.
Please help if anyone has ever faced a similar situation.

Seems to me as some kind of a bug with the AVD.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a AVD as you specified. But, I did not find the option "Motorola Razr M (540 x 960)" in "Device" drop-down list. Did you download anything specific using Android SDK Manager to get Motorola AVD?

Comment: I cannot add a comment to your question. That's why I had to post it as an answer.

Comment: You will have to create a new device for that in AVD Manager --> "Device Definition"(tab) --> "New Device". Anyways, my issue was resolved long back. The only thing i had to do was use the proper Android OS version --> 2.3.3 for Motorola Razr. Previously i had selected Android 4.2.2 and hence the problem.